# When to click form input the background is changing weirdly and after clicking page is not loading correctly on the phone

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

When I click the input the page is going crazy on the phone. There is not problem on the desktop. I believe the problem is because of the CSS but couldn't figure it out. I am a beginner designer and I am working on responsive web designers. When I click the input the background changes and page is not loading correctly.

This is the HTML of the site

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
  position: relative;
  background-image: url("pop-zebra-4q3Ogm3Kt44-unsplash.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
}

body::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)
}

#all {
  position: absolute;
  right: 50%;
  bottom: 50%;
  transform: translate(50%, 50%);
  padding: 3rem;
  z-index: 1;
  color: #fff;
}

.showcase-top {
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 2rem;
}

.showcase-top h1 {
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: 900;
  margin-bottom: 0.8rem;
}

.showcase-top p {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  letter-spacing: 5px
}

#second {
  margin-top: 0.2rem
}

.tabs {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2rem;
}

.tab {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid rgba(166, 151, 7, 0.8);
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 2rem;
}

.tabs .tab h1 {
  margin-top: 0.9rem;
}

.form {
  padding: 0.5rem 5rem;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 2.5rem;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 900px;
  padding: 10px 50px;
  margin-left: 0.6rem;
}

.form input {
  width: 70%;
  padding: 0.8rem;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 1.5rem;
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
  outline: none;
}

.form button {
  width: 25%;
  padding: 0.8rem;
  border-radius: 1.5rem;
  border: none;
  background-color: #a69802;
  color: #edece1;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}

.footer {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 6px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-10%, 51%);
  letter-spacing: 1px
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
  .tabs {
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-left: 0.6rem;
  }
  .tab {
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    height: 90px;
    width: 90px;
  }
  .form {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 1rem;
    margin-left: 1rem;
    margin-top: -3rem;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .form button {
    width: 100px;
  }
  .showcase-top {
    width: 500px;
    margin-left: 1rem;
  }
  .showcase-top h1 {
    font-size: 2rem;
  }
  .showcase-top p {
    font-size: 1rem;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width:320px) and (max-width:480px) {
  .form {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    margin: auto;
  }
  .form input {
    width: 65%;
  }
  .form button {
    width: 40%;
    margin-top: 1rem;
  }
  .showcase-top p {
    font-size: 0.7rem
  }
  .tabs {
    padding: 0;
    padding-top: 1.2rem
  }
  .tab {
    height: 90px;
    width: 90px;
  }
  .footer {
    bottom: 15%;
    left: 23%
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <showcase id="all">
    <div class="showcase-top">
      <h1>Coming Soon</h1>
      <p>My website is under construction</p>
      <p id="second">Follow us now!</p>
    </div>
    <section class="tabs">
      <div class="tab">
        <h1 id="day">na</h1>
        <p>Days</p>
      </div>
      <div class="tab">
        <h1 id="hour">na</h1>
        <p>Hours</p>
      </div>
      <div class="tab">
        <h1 id="min">na</h1>
        <p>Minutes</p>
      </div>
      <div class="tab">
        <h1 id="sec">na</h1>
        <p>Seconds</p>
      </div>
    </section>
    <form class="form">
      <input type="email" placeholder="Enter Email...">
      <button type="submit">Subscribe</button>
    </form>
  </showcase>
  <footer class="footer">
    <h1>Designed by Cag | Copyright &copy; 2021</h1>
  </footer>
```

Comment: you can visit the web page to see the error.  =      cagatayem.com

Comment: Everything is working fine in my browser?

Comment: the problem is on the phone.Can you check it on the phone pls

Comment: Yes, it's working fine. There is no flickering and background doesn't change when i click on input.

Comment: when i click the enter email background is changing. i will try to upload a pic

Comment: https://ibb.co/Tttxgdn you can the change here

Comment: Oh, that is because your keyboard pushes all content up. Try removing `overflow: hidden` to your showcase container.

Comment: I don't get any difference on the phone either.

Comment: why its happens only on my phone :DD  okey i will try and i will let you know. Thank you guys

Comment: and off to topic what do you think about css parts. i mean the code. Is it okey or needs a lot improvements ?

Comment: No you have problems in your layout, the different parts are overlapping. See your own snippet when the height is small. I think this is the cause of your problems.

Comment: You'd have to check everything to make it cleaner. But as a guide I would use less or no `absolute` (don't think you need this here), more `flex` if needed.

Comment: okey thanks guys i will check them